# Can not get validation during json deserialization with django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a django application that fetch data from an API.
The json I get looks like this :

```
{
   "id":"game_id",
   "players":{
      "white":{
         "user":{
            "name":"player1",
            "id":"player1"
         },
         "rating":11,
         "stars":58
      },
      "black":{
         "user":{
            "name":"player2",
            "id":"player2"
         },
         "rating":10,
         "stars":52
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to deserialize it to insert data in a "game" database :

```
class User(models.Model):

    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Game(models.Model):

    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=15)
    white = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="white_id", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    white_rating = models.IntegerField()
    white_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

with the following serializers :

```
class PlayersSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        white = data.get("players").get("white")
        white_id = white.get("user").get("id")
        white_rating = white.get("rating")
        white_stars = white.get("stars")

        return {"white": white_id, "white_rating": white_rating, "white_stars": white_stars}

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    white = PlayersSerializer()
    white_rating = PlayersSerializer()
    white_stars = PlayersSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ["id", "white", "white_rating", "white_stars"]
```

When in the view file I check GameSerialization.is_valid(data), I get the following error:

```
{'white': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'white_rating': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'white_stars': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

Comment: i think so, in gameSerializer, you have to call Playerserialzier once

Comment: white = PlayersSerializer() that's enough, remove other nested serializer